# EWS : Canceling a Recurring Occurrence

Tags: .net, exchangewebservices, ews-managed-api

I'm trying to cancel a recurring occurrence with the same account I created this recurring appointment with. I'm getting this error :

```
User must be an organizer for CancelCalendarItem action
```

When I check the properties of the appointment, I find that the organizer has the same SMTP address as the one used by the service. The error doesn't make sense.

Do I need to impersonate the resource (room) email to be able to cancel the meeting?

I'm trying to cancel a single occurrence of a series of appointments. Booking Code:

```
Appointment appointment = new Appointment(service);

            appointment.Subject = Subject;
            appointment.Body = Body;
            appointment.Start = Start;

            foreach (DataRow room in Rooms.Rows)
            {
                appointment.Resources.Add(room["Email"].ToString());
            }
if (Recurring)
            {
                DayOfTheWeek[] days = new DayOfTheWeek[] { (DayOfTheWeek)Start.DayOfWeek };
                appointment.Recurrence = new Recurrence.WeeklyPattern(Start.Date, 1, days);
                appointment.Recurrence.StartDate = Start;
                appointment.Recurrence.NumberOfOccurrences = RecurringOccurances;
            }
appointment.Save(SendInvitationsMode.SendToAllAndSaveCopy);
```

Getting Recurring Appointments :

```
public static DataTable GetRecurringItems(String ID)
        {    
            Appointment recurringMasterItem = Appointment.BindToRecurringMaster(service, new ItemId(ID));
            DataTable RecurringAppoitnments = new DataTable();
            int Occs = recurringMasterItem.Recurrence.NumberOfOccurrences.Value;
            for (int i = 1; i <= Occs; i++)
            {
                Appointment occurrenceOrException2 = Appointment.BindToOccurrence(service, new ItemId(recurringMasterItem.Id.UniqueId), i);
                RecurringAppoitnments.Rows.Add(occurrenceOrException2);

            }

            return RecurringAppoitnments;
        }
```

//Then I chose 1 of the recurring occurrences above to cancel it :

```
Appointment appointment = Appointment.Bind(service, new ItemId(EWSID));
appointment.CancelMeeting();
```

I get the "User must be an organizer for CancelCalendarItem action" when I try to cancel the meeting although all the actions above created using the same user/account.

Comment: Show some code. What is 'cancelling a recurring occurrence', are you trying to delete one occurrence of a repeating event?

Comment: @JanDoggen : Thanks for the note, I just updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try impersonate the user to cancel the meeting. Also make sure that the ID has enough permission to perform this action.